# vue-recaptcha doesn't work with laravel 8 and vue 2.6

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, vue-recaptcha

I'm trying to implement vue-recaptcha in my laravel 8, vue 2.6 application. I'm following [vue-recaptcha documentation](https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha) but it doesn't show anything.
Here is my vue file:

```
const { VueRecaptcha } = require("vue-recaptcha");

new Vue({
    el: '#home',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    components: {
        'vue-recaptcha': VueRecaptcha,
      },
    data: () => ({
        url: dir,
        sitekey: 'mykey',
    }),
    methods: {
      onSubmit: function () {
            this.$refs.invisibleRecaptcha.execute()
      },
      onVerify: function (response) {
            console.log('Verify: ' + response)
      },
      onExpired: function () {
            console.log('Expired')
      },
      resetRecaptcha() {
            this.$refs.recaptcha.reset() // Direct call reset method
      },
    }
```

This is my view.blade

```
<v-container>
    <v-row sm="12">
        <v-col  xs="12" md="6" sm="12">
            <v-form
                ref="form"
                v-model="valid"
                lazy-validation
            >
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="name"
                    counter="10"
                    :rules="rules.select"
                    label="Name *"

                    required
                ></v-text-field>

                <v-text-field
                    v-model="email"
                    label="Email *"
                    required
                    :rules="rules.emailRules"
                ></v-text-field>

                <v-textarea
                    label="Message *"
                    v-model="message"
                    auto-grow
                    required
                    :rules="rules.select"
                ></v-textarea>
                aqui va el captcha
                <div>
                    <vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="onVerify" @expired="onExpired" :sitekey="sitekey"> </vue-recaptcha>
                    <button @click="resetRecaptcha">Reset ReCAPTCHA</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>Bind ReCAPTCHA to button</h3>
                    <vue-recaptcha @verify="onVerify" @expired="onExpired" :sitekey="sitekey">
                        <button>Click me</button>
                    </vue-recaptcha>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>Invisible ReCAPTCHA</h3>
                    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
                        <vue-recaptcha
                            ref="invisibleRecaptcha"
                            @verify="onVerify"
                            @expired="onExpired"
                            size="invisible"
                            :sitekey="sitekey"
                        >
                        </vue-recaptcha>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                aqui termina el captcha
                <vue-recaptcha  :sitekey="sitekey">
                    <button>Click me</button>
                </vue-recaptcha>
                <v-btn
                    :disabled="!valid"
                    color="primary"
                    @click="send"
                >
                    send
                </v-btn>
            </v-form>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="pa-6"
               xs="12"
               md="6"
               sm="12"
        >
            <v-row class="mb-1" >
                <ul style="text-decoration: none">
                    <li><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">Contacts</span><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-home</v-icon>  Company<br></li>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-phone</v-icon><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">  Phone:</span><a class="header_text" href="tel:1 (800) 123-1042"> 1 (800) 123-1042 </a><br></li>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-envelope</v-icon><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">  Email:</span> <a class="header_text" href="mailto:info@gmail.com">info@gmail.com</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">Business Hours</span><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-clock-o</v-icon><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">  Monday-Friday:</span> 7:30am to 10:00pm<br></li>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-clock-o</v-icon><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">  Saturday:</span> 7:30am to 7:00pm<br></li>
                            <li><v-icon small color="#00ADE5">fa-clock-o</v-icon><span style="font-size: larger; font-weight: bold">  Sunday:</span> 7:30am to 7:00pm<br></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </v-row>

        </v-col>
    </v-row>

</v-container>
```

In my layout.blade I put this code:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit"
            async
            defer
        ></script>
```

I'm testing all three options described in documentation, reset captcha, bind to buttom, and invisible captcha, neither works.

And this is what I get:
[image]

Versions:

- "vue": "^2.6.1"
- "vue-recaptcha": "^2.0.2"
- laravel 8

I don't know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Better try using vue-nocaptcha

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).